# Stray footer floating over content in Wordpress Page

Tags: php, html, wordpress

We built our site in Wordpress and everything was perfect but then we wanted to add a blog and the footer was behaving strangely floating over the main content instead of at the bottom of the page where it should be.

We tried adding a top-margin to fix the problem but that's probably not a good idea...

The pages can be seen here:

#### .com.au/tinting-eyebrows

#### .com.au/?s=eyebrows

Any help on how to fix this properly would be GREATLY appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what does **div.box** outside the wrapper, just delete its height on your CSS and problem solved:

On your **style.css** at line 413, **remove/comment** the following rule:

```
    /*height: 170px*/
```

And everything should work. Because that div is limiting the primary_content_wrap's height and making the footer displaying at a higher position.